# LINQ custom class query with parameters select

Tags: c#, linq, webapi

I need to get a linq query for custom class MyFileData

```
public class MyFileData 
{
    private string name;
    private string last_mod;
    private string file_type;
    private long size;

    public string Name 
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string LastMod
    {
        get { return last_mod; }
        set { last_mod = value; }
    }

    public long Size
    {
        get { return size; }
        set { size = value; }
    }

    public string FileType
    {
        get { return file_type;}
        set { file_type = value; }
    }
}
```

but I want as an output values of all properties without file_type like this

```
from file in files
    select new MyFileData
    {
        Name = file.Name,
        LastMod = file.LastMod,
        Size = file.Size,
    };
```

so the output without the "fileType"

```
[{"name":"desktop.ini","lastMod":"07.12.2019 10:12:42","size":174,"fileType":null}]
```

in this way

```
[{"name":"desktop.ini","lastMod":"07.12.2019 10:12:42","size":174}]
```

also I would like to group the files with the type of the extension like that

```
from file in files
group file by file.FileType;
```

but I get an error.

The files is `IEnumerable<MyFileData>` type.

Below whole endpoint map for the program:

```
app.MapGet($"/browse", (string? path, string? group, MyGetFilesInfo myGetFilesInfo) =>
{
IEnumerable<MyFileData> files = myGetFilesInfo.GetFiles(path);

if (group == "true")
{
    return
        from file in files
        select file;
}

var query = 
    from file in files
    select new MyFileData
    {
        Name = file.Name,
        LastMod = file.LastMod,
        Size = file.Size,
    };

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
});
```

Comment: Please add the exact error message.

Comment: CS1593 Delegate 'RequestDelegate' does not take 3 arguments

Comment: It's in case of trying to use group ... by , considering only the first part, the program compiles, but as mentioned the output is the whole MyFileData object with all properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simple way, you can try to use an anonymous class

```
files.Select(x=> new { 
    Name = x.Name,
    LastMod = x.LastMod,
    Size = x.Size
});
```

**Edit**

The error is caused because your endpoint returns two different types that will let the compiler confuse.

You can try to use `Results.Json` method Unite that return your JSON string.

```
app.MapGet($"/browse", (string? path, string? group, MyGetFilesInfo myGetFilesInfo) =>
{
    IEnumerable<MyFileData> files = myGetFilesInfo.GetFiles(path);

    if (group == "true")
    {
        return Results.Json(files);
    }

    var query = 
        from file in files
        select new 
        {
            Name = file.Name,
            LastMod = file.LastMod,
            Size = file.Size
        };

    return Results.Json(query);
});
```

Comment: I tried with this, but then the CS1593 also occurs

Comment: @KubaJ I edit my answer as lambda you can try it

Comment: Even with lambda it gives CS1593

Comment: @KubaJ Could you provide your full code of files? your error seem like be another thing.

Comment: I've added it to the main question

Comment: @KubaJ I edit my answer you can try it

Comment: It works! Thank you so much :) Sorry if this was a bit silly question, I'm totally new to webapi

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set null value handling in the `JsonProperty` attribute. Setting `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` makes null values ignored when serializing or deserializing objects.

```
[JsonProperty("fileType", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string FileType
{
    get { return file_type;}
    set { file_type = value; }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding attribute but it still returns the fileType property

Comment: Could you post the code you use to create the JSON string, please?

Comment: JObject querry =
    new JObject(
        new JArray(
            from file in files
            select new JObject(
                new JProperty("name", file.Name),
                new JProperty("lastMod", file.LastMod),
                new JProperty("size", file.Size)))
        );

Comment: For the `JsonProperty` attribute to work, you would need to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` instead of manually created `JObject`.

Comment: so I've tried also with Serializing object (shown in the end of the main question), but it still does not work with the same error

Comment: The error CS1593 you mention in the question comments is probably not related to JSON serialization. It is a different issue.